# ¿Como mostrar un arbol de forma horizontal en C?

Tags: c, matrices, recursión, árboles-binarios, sourcetree

IDEA INICIAL: La idea era tomar el recorrido INORDEN para obtener un array, con cada uno de los numeros a mostrar. Generar una matriz por ancho de fila de (cantidadNodos) y por filas (altura). Para mostrarlos en la matriz usando el indice que iteraria el array y el nivel de ese nodo, para ser colocados en la matriz y posteriormente ser mostrado en pantalla.

```
//               (8)
//             /      \
//           6         10
//          /  \       / \
//         4    7     9   11
//        / \  / \   / \ /  \
//       1   5               13
//      / \ / \             /  \
//                         12
```

La idea es que se muestre de esta forma, he intentado varias alternativas con matrices y soluciones recursivas. Gracias de antemano, cualquier ayuda me puede servir

Les dejo el codigo

```
/*
    Codigo de Arbol AVL
    Implementado por: Ulises Rodriguez y Josue Rojas
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//utilidades
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

//definicion de TAD
typedef struct ArbolAVL {
    int valor; // valor principal
    struct ArbolAVL *izq; // lado izquierdo
    struct ArbolAVL *der; // lado derecho
    int altura; // altura del nodo
}ArbolAVL;

// declaracion de funciones
ArbolAVL *crearArbol(int);
ArbolAVL *insertarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *,int);
ArbolAVL *eliminarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *,int);
void mostrarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *,int);
void mostrarPreOrden(ArbolAVL *);
void mostrarInOrden(ArbolAVL *);
void mostrarPostOrden(ArbolAVL *);
int profundidad( ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarDerecha(ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarIzquierda(ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarSimpleIzquierda(ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarSimpleDerecha(ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarDobleDerecha(ArbolAVL *);
ArbolAVL *rotarDobleIzquierda(ArbolAVL *);
int calcularFactorBalance(ArbolAVL *);
int contieneElemento(ArbolAVL *, int);
ArbolAVL *buscarNodo(ArbolAVL *, int);
int cantidadNodos(ArbolAVL *);
int buscarNivel(ArbolAVL *, int, int);
ArbolAVL *copiarArbol(ArbolAVL*);

ArbolAVL *ARBOL = NULL;


/*COPIAR ARBOL DADO*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ArbolAVL *copiarArbol(ArbolAVL *ARBOL) {
    if(ARBOL) { // si el arbol existe
        ArbolAVL *copia = (ArbolAVL *) malloc(sizeof(ArbolAVL)); // reservamos espacio en memoria
        copia->der = ARBOL->der; // igualamos el lado derecho
        copia->izq = ARBOL->izq; // igualamos el lado izquierdo
        copia->valor = ARBOL->valor; // igualamos su dato

        // igualamos cada dato del arbol

        return copia; // retornamos la copia de ese valor
    } return NULL;   // en caso no haber arbol por copiar 
}

ArbolAVL *crearArbol(int valor) {
    ArbolAVL *nuevo = (ArbolAVL *) malloc(sizeof(ArbolAVL));
    nuevo->valor = valor;
    nuevo->der = nuevo->izq = NULL;
    return nuevo;
}

/**BUSCAR NODO Y RETORNARLO*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int buscarNivel(ArbolAVL *ARBOL, int valor, int nivel) {
    if (ARBOL) { // si hay arbol para buscar el valor
        if (ARBOL->valor == valor) // si corresponde el valor, se retorna el nivel
            return nivel;   
        else {
            if (valor > ARBOL->valor) // si es mayor se busca por lado derecho
                return buscarNivel(ARBOL->der, valor, nivel+1);
            else // si es menos o igual por el lado izquierdo
                return buscarNivel(ARBOL->izq, valor, nivel+1);
        }
    } else
        return -1; // sino existe en el arbol
}

void imprimirMenu() {
    // menu principal
    printf("\n\n--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("(ArbolAVL):                           \n");
    printf(" [1].Insertar Raiz                        \n");
    printf(" [2].Insertar Elemento                    \n");
    printf(" [3].Borrar Nodo                          \n");
    printf(" [4].Buscar Elemento                      \n");
    printf(" [5].Mostrar ArbolAVL                     \n");
    printf(" [6].Mostrar preorden                     \n");
    printf(" [7].Mostrar inorden                      \n");
    printf(" [8].Mostrar postorden                    \n");
    printf(" [9].Salir                               \n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n\n");
}

void ingresoNumero(int *n) {
    int bandera; // representa la entrada correcta del dato
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero\n");
    do { // mientras la entrada no sea valida
        bandera = scanf("%i", &(*n));
        if (bandera == 0) { // caso donde la entrada sea invalida
            getchar();
            printf("Ingrese un numero entero valido:\n");
            continue; // vuelve a preguntar
        }
    } while (bandera == 0);
}

void mostrar(ArbolAVL *ARBOL) {
    // muestra un encabezado para la visualizacion del arbol
    printf("\n**************************************\n\n");
    printf("Mostrando ARBOL:                  \n");
    if (ARBOL != NULL) mostrarArbolAVL(ARBOL, 0); // si existe el arbol lo muestra
    else printf("El ARBOL esta vacio"); // sino da el mensaje
    printf("\n\n**************************************\n");
}

/**BUSCAR NODO Y RETORNAR SI ESTA O NO*////////////////////////////////////////////
int contieneElemento(ArbolAVL *ARBOL, int valor) {
    if (ARBOL) { // si hay donde buscar
        if (ARBOL->valor == valor) // si es el valor correcto
            return TRUE; // caso existe en el arbol
        else {
            if (!contieneElemento(ARBOL->der, valor)) // busca al lado derecho
                if (!contieneElemento(ARBOL->izq, valor)) // busca al lado izquierdo
                    return FALSE; // caso no existe en el arbol
        }
    } else 
        return FALSE; // no hay donde buscar
}

/**BUSCAR NODO Y RETORNARLO*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ArbolAVL *buscarNodo(ArbolAVL *ARBOL, int valor) {
    if (ARBOL) { // si hay arbol en donde buscar
        if (ARBOL->valor == valor) // si se encuentra se retorna una copia de ese arbol
            return copiarArbol(ARBOL);
        else { // si no es el arbol que corresponde
            if (!buscarNodo(ARBOL->der, valor)) // se busca al lado derecho
                if (!buscarNodo(ARBOL->izq, valor)) // se busca al lado izquierdo
                    return NULL; // caso donde no se encuentre en el arbol
        }
    } return NULL; // sino hay arbol a buscar, no existe el valor
}

void mostrarBusqueda(ArbolAVL *arbol, int n, int valorBuscado) {
    if (!arbol) // si no hay arbol a mostrar
        return;
    else { // si hay arbol a mostrar
        mostrarBusqueda(arbol->der, n+1, valorBuscado); // muestra por el lado derecho
        for (int i=0; i<n; printf("\t"),i++); // corre los espacios
        if (arbol->valor != valorBuscado) printf("%d\n", arbol->valor); // si no es el buscado, solo se muestra
        else printf("[%d]\n", arbol->valor); // si es el valor buscado, lo encierra
        mostrarBusqueda(arbol->izq, n+1, valorBuscado); // muestra por el lado izquierdo
    }
}

/*CANTIDAD DE NODOS*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int cantidadNodos(ArbolAVL *ARBOL) {
    if (ARBOL) // si existe arbol por contar, se retorna 1 (se cuenta a si mismo) y la suma de su lados
        return 1 + cantidadNodos(ARBOL->izq) + cantidadNodos(ARBOL->der);
    else
        return 0;  // si no hay arbol no se cuenta
}


void mostrarDatosNodo(ArbolAVL *raiz, ArbolAVL *ARBOL) {
    if (ARBOL) { // si hay arbol a mostrar
        // datos a mostrar del nodo
        printf("\n[Nodo (%d): nivel(%d), altura(%d), cantidadNodosHijos(%d)]", \
            ARBOL->valor, buscarNivel(raiz, ARBOL->valor, 0), profundidad(ARBOL)-1, cantidadNodos(ARBOL)-1 );
    }
}

int main() {
    extern ArbolAVL *ARBOL;
    char opcion[100]; // buffer de entrada del usuario
    int opcionMenu; // entrada del usuario, uso del menu

    do { 
        imprimirMenu();
        fgets(opcion,100,stdin); // recibe los caracteres de entrada del usuario
        opcionMenu = atoi(opcion); // toma el numero encontrado en la cadena
        switch(opcionMenu) { // segun la opcion dada
            case 1:  /*insertarRaiz*/
                if (!ARBOL) { // si no existe el arbol
                    int numero; 
                    ingresoNumero(&numero); // entrada de usuario
                    ARBOL = crearArbol(numero); // inicializa el arbol con el valor dado
                    mostrar(ARBOL); // muestra el arbol
                    getchar();
                } else // caso donde ya existe una raiz 
                    printf("Ya se ha ingresado una raiz\n"); 
            break;

            case 2: /*insertar*/
                if (ARBOL) { // si existe el arbol
                    int numero;
                    ingresoNumero(&numero); // entrada de usuario
                    if (contieneElemento(ARBOL, numero)){
                        printf("Ya existe este elemento en el arbol");        
                    }
                    else{
                        ARBOL = insertarArbolAVL(ARBOL, numero); // insertar el valor en el arbol
                        mostrar(ARBOL); // muestra el arbol
                    }
                } else // caso donde el arbol no exista aun
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                getchar();
            break;

            case 3: // eliminar
                if (!ARBOL)// sino existe el arbol
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                else { // si el arbol ya existe
                    int eliminar;
                    ingresoNumero(&eliminar); // entrada del usuario
                    eliminarArbolAVL(ARBOL, eliminar); // elimina el valor dado
                    mostrar(ARBOL); // muestra el arbol
                    getchar();
                }
            break;

            case 4: // buscar
                if (!ARBOL) { // si no hay arbol donde buscar
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                } else { // si hay arbol donde buscar
                    int busqueda;
                    ingresoNumero(&busqueda); // entrada del usuario
                    ArbolAVL *nodoBuscado = buscarNodo(ARBOL, busqueda); //guarda el nodo buscado
                    if (nodoBuscado) { // si lo encontro
                        printf("\n");
                        mostrarBusqueda(ARBOL, 0, nodoBuscado->valor); // muestra entre [x], donde x es el valor buscado
                        mostrarDatosNodo(ARBOL, nodoBuscado); // muestra los datos referentes al arbol
                    } else // sino lo encuentra
                        printf("No se ha encontrado el nodo solicitado\n");
                }
                getchar();
            break;

            case 5: // mostrar ARBOL
                if (!ARBOL)// si no hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Arbol vacio: Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                else // si hay arbol a mostrar
                    mostrar(ARBOL);
                getchar();
            break;

            case 6: // mostrar preorden
                if (!ARBOL) // si no hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                else { // si hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Preorden: ");
                    mostrarPreOrden(ARBOL);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            break;

            case 7: // mostrar inorden
                if (!ARBOL) // si no hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                else { // si hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Inorden: ");
                    mostrarInOrden(ARBOL);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            break;

            case 8: // mostrar postorden
                if (!ARBOL)// si no hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Debe ingresar la raiz primero\n");
                else { // si hay arbol a mostrar
                    printf("Postorden: ");
                    mostrarPostOrden(ARBOL);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            break;

            case 9: // salir del programa
                printf("\nHa salido del programa\n"); 
            break;

            default: { // caso de una opcion que no corresponda a las mostradas
                printf("Opcion inválida");
            }
        }
        getchar(); // espera una tecla por parte del usuario
        system("clear"); // limpia la pantallar
    } while (opcionMenu != 9); // se ejecuta mientras la opcion no corresponda a salir

}

ArbolAVL * insertarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *arbol, int valor) {
    if(arbol == NULL) { // si no hay arbol
        arbol = crearArbol(valor); // crea uno nuevo
    } else if(valor > arbol->valor) {   // insertar al lado derecho del arbol
        arbol->der = insertarArbolAVL(arbol->der,valor); // se agrega el valor y se procede a revisar
        if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol) == -2) // si su factor de balance no esta entre [-1, 1]
            if(valor > arbol->der->valor) // se coloca a la derecha
                arbol = rotarSimpleIzquierda(arbol); // rotacion simple izquierda
            else
                arbol = rotarDobleIzquierda(arbol); // rotacion doble izquierda
    } else if(valor < arbol->valor) {  // se coloca a la izquierda
        arbol->izq = insertarArbolAVL(arbol->izq,valor); // se agrega el valor y se procede a revisar
        if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol) == 2) // si su factor de balance no esta entre [-1, 1]
            if(valor < arbol->izq->valor)
                arbol = rotarSimpleDerecha(arbol); // rotar simple derecha
            else
                arbol = rotarDobleDerecha(arbol); // rotar doble derecha
    }
    arbol->altura = profundidad(arbol); // se calcula la profundidad
    return(arbol);
}

ArbolAVL * eliminarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *arbol,int valor) {
    ArbolAVL *aux; // auxiliar para iterar
    if(!arbol) // si no hay arbol 
        return NULL;
    else
        if(valor > arbol->valor) {  // si el valor a borrar es mayor se mueve a la derecha
            arbol->der = eliminarArbolAVL(arbol->der,valor); 
            if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol) == 2) // si su factor de balance no esta entre [-1, 1s]
                if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol->izq) >= 0) // segun el factor de balance del izquierdo
                    arbol = rotarSimpleDerecha(arbol); // rotacion simple a la derecha
                else
                    arbol=rotarDobleDerecha(arbol); // rotacion doble a la derecha
        } else if(valor < arbol->valor) { // si el valor a borrar es menor
                arbol->izq = eliminarArbolAVL(arbol->izq,valor); // nos movemos a la izquierda
                if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol) == -2)  // si su factor de balance es -2, rotacion izquierda
                    if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol->der) <= 0) // si su factor de balance esta entre [-2, 0]
                        arbol = rotarSimpleIzquierda(arbol); // rotamos simple derecha
                    else
                        arbol = rotarDobleIzquierda(arbol); // rotamos doble derecha
        } else { // si encontramos el valor
            if(arbol->der != NULL) { // si su rama derecha existe
                aux = arbol->der; // para iterar
                while(aux->izq) // mientras exista rama izquierda
                    aux = aux->izq; // se mueve a la izquierda
                arbol->valor = aux->valor;
                arbol->der = eliminarArbolAVL(arbol->der,aux->valor); //eliminarArbolAVL en mostrarInOrden
                if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol) == 2) // si su factor de balance es 2, rotacion derecha
                    if(calcularFactorBalance(arbol->izq) >= 0) // si el factor de balance de su rama izquierda es mayor a 0
                        arbol = rotarSimpleDerecha(arbol); // rotacion simple derecha
                    else
                        arbol = rotarDobleDerecha(arbol); // rotacion doble derecha
            } else // si no existe el lado derecho
                return(arbol->izq);
        }
    arbol->altura = profundidad(arbol); // calculamos su profundidad
    return(arbol);
}

int profundidad(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    int alturaIzquierda,alturaDerecha; // variables locales para ambos lados
    if(!arbol) // si no hay arbol 
        return 0;
    if(!arbol->izq) // si no hay arbol izquierdo
        alturaIzquierda = 0; // 
    else // si existe el lado izquierdo
        alturaIzquierda = 1 + arbol->izq->altura; 

    if(!arbol->der) // si no hay arbol derecho
        alturaDerecha = 0; 
    else // si hay arbol derecho
        alturaDerecha= 1 + arbol->der->altura;

    if(alturaIzquierda > alturaDerecha) // def: 1 + max(alturaDer, alturaIzq)
        return alturaIzquierda; // caso izquierda de mayor altura
    return(alturaDerecha); // caso derecha o altura 0
}

ArbolAVL * rotarDerecha(ArbolAVL *valor) {
    ArbolAVL *aux; // auxiliar
    aux = valor->izq;      //              (x)              (y)
    valor->izq = aux->der; //           (y)       ==>   (z)     (x)
    aux->der = valor;      //        (z)
    valor->altura = profundidad(valor); // calcular profundidad del nodo derecho
    aux->altura = profundidad(aux); // calcular profuncidad del nodo arbol 
    return(aux);
}

ArbolAVL * rotarIzquierda(ArbolAVL *valor) {
    ArbolAVL *aux; // auxiliar
    aux = valor->der;        //         (x)                     (y)
    valor->der = aux->izq; //              (y)      ==>      (x)   (z)
    aux->izq = valor;      //                 (z)
    valor->altura = profundidad(valor); // calcular produndidad del nodo izquierdo
    aux->altura = profundidad(aux); // calcular profundidad del nodo arbol 
    return(aux);
}

ArbolAVL * rotarSimpleIzquierda(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    arbol=rotarIzquierda(arbol); // rotamos a la izquierda el arbol dado
    return(arbol); 
}

ArbolAVL * rotarSimpleDerecha(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    arbol = rotarDerecha(arbol); // rotamos a la derecha el arbol dado
    return(arbol);
}

ArbolAVL * rotarDobleDerecha(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    arbol->izq=rotarIzquierda(arbol->izq); //           (x)                 (x)             (z)
    arbol=rotarDerecha(arbol);             //       (y)         ==>      (z)      ==>   (y)     (x)
    return(arbol);                         //          (z)             (y)
}

ArbolAVL * rotarDobleIzquierda(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    arbol->der=rotarDerecha(arbol->der);   //       (x)                  (x)                 (z)
    arbol = rotarIzquierda(arbol);         //           (y)     ==>         (z)      ==>  (x)   (y)
    return(arbol);                         //        (z)                       (y)
}

int calcularFactorBalance(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    int alturaIzquierda,alturaDerecha; // factorbalance = alturaIzq - alturaDerecha
    if(!arbol) // si no hay arbol
        return 0;
    if(!arbol->izq) // si no hay lado izquierdo
        alturaIzquierda = 0;
    else
        alturaIzquierda = 1 + arbol->izq->altura;

    if(!arbol->der) // si no hay lado derecho
        alturaDerecha = 0;
    else
        alturaDerecha = 1 + arbol->der->altura;
    // al calcular sus altura se devuelve la resta de la derecha a la izquierda
    return(alturaIzquierda-alturaDerecha);
}

void mostrarPreOrden(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    if(arbol) {  // si existe un arbol por mostrar, mostrar cada uno de sus lados
        printf("%d,",arbol->valor);
        mostrarPreOrden(arbol->izq); // RID (Raiz, Izquierda, Derecha)
        mostrarPreOrden(arbol->der);
    }
}

void mostrarInOrden(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    if(arbol) { // si existe un arbol por mostrar, mostrar cada uno de sus lados
        mostrarInOrden(arbol->izq);
        printf("%d,",arbol->valor); // IRD (Izquierda, Raiz, Derecha)
        mostrarInOrden(arbol->der);
    }
}

void mostrarPostOrden(ArbolAVL *arbol) {
    if(arbol) { // si existe un arbol por mostrar, mostrar cada uno de sus lados
        mostrarPostOrden(arbol->izq);
        printf("%d,",arbol->valor); // IDR (Izquierda, Derecha, Raiz)
        mostrarPostOrden(arbol->der);
    }
}

void mostrarArbolAVL(ArbolAVL *arbol, int n) {
    if (!arbol) // si no hay arbol a mostrar
        return;
    else { // si hay arbol por mostrar
        mostrarArbolAVL(arbol->der, n+1); // mostrar su lado derecho
        for (int i=0; i<n; printf("\t"),i++); // correr los espacios
        printf("%d\n", arbol->valor); // mostrar valor de la arbol 
         mostrarArbolAVL(arbol->izq, n+1); // mostrar su lado izquierdo
    }
}
```

Comment: El cinco no está conectado al cuatro y al siete ¿no?

Comment: Esta conectado al lado derecho del 4, pero la idea es que con respecto a la cantidad de nodos en el arbol se redimensione para cubrir mejor el espacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>***Respuesta parcial***</s>

Estuve pensando en el problema y llegué a lo siguientes requerimientos antes de dibujar (No está completo):

- Debes tener la profundidad del árbol (`d`)
- Debes definir un número de caracteres a imprimir por valor (`c`)
- Se define `l` como el nivel a imprimir
- Se calcula un número de espacios de separación `s` dependiendo del nivel `l`
- Se calcula un numero de espacios a imprimir antes y después de cada fila (`p`)

Por  ejemplo, si se define `c=3`, los valores se imprimirían como `"  1"`, `" 10"`, etc (usando el formato `%3d`). Y ahora usando el mismo árbol que muestras y  agregando valores de relleno, muestro como lo dibujaría, usando como caracter `p` puntos y caracter de separación `s` guiones.

```
// c=3,d=4
//
//...............................(8)                               // l:0,s:0,p:31
//                 _______________|_______________
//                |                               |
//............... 6 ----------------------------- 10               // l:1,s:29,p:15
//         _______|_______                 _______|_______
//        |               |               |               |
//....... 4 ------------- 7 ------------- 9 ------------- 11       // l:2,s:13,p:7
//     ___|___         ___|___         ___|____        ___|___ 
//    |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
//... 1 ----- 5 -----XXX-----YYY-----ZZZ-----AAA-----BBB-----13    // l:3,s:5,p:3
//   _|_     _|_     _|_                                     _|_   
//  |   |   |   |   |   |                                   |   |
//.xxx-yyy-zzz-aaa-bbb-ccc                                  12-ddd.// l:4,s:1,p:1
//
```

He usado diferentes caracteres para dibujar las ramas, la parte que falta es encontrar la relación entre la ubicación del nodo (fila y rama) e imprimir los espacios correspondientes.

hasta el momento, las relaciones que tengo son:

- filas a imprimir `r = 3*d + 1`
- columnas requeridas `w = (c+1)*(1<<d) + 1` (sin contar caracter nulo `\0`)
- Número de espacios de separación en cada fila dependiendo del nivel `l`, `s = c*((1<<(d-l))-1)+(1<<(d-l))`
- Número de espacios antes y después en cada fila dependiendo del nivel `l`, `p = (w - (c*(1<<l)) - (s*((1<<l)-1)) )/2`

---

Al implementar esto en C, asumiendo los valores del árbol en un arreglo, obtuve esto (No es lo que debería, es cuestión de darle el formato requerido y eliminar las ramas sin valores):

```
depth: 4, c: 3, max_elem: 31
                                 8                               
                  _______________________________
                 6                              10               
          _______________                 _______________
         4               7               9              11       
      _______         _______         _______         _______
     1       5                                              13   
    ___     ___     ___     ___     ___     ___     ___     ___
                                                          12
```

Y ahora lo más complicado... el código (Perdón por lo desordenado e ineficiente):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define D           (4)
#define D2          (1<<D)
#define C           (3)
#define MAX_ELEMENTS    ((1<<D+1)-1)
#define W       D2*(C+1)+1
#define R       (3*D + 1)


void main(){
    int tree_values[MAX_ELEMENTS] = {8,6,10,4,7,9,11,1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,13,-1,-1,-1,-1,
    -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,12,-1};

    printf("depth: %d, c: %d, max_elem: %d\n",D,C,MAX_ELEMENTS);

    char curr_line[W+1] = " ";
    int max_el_line = 0;
    int curr_idx = 0;
    int x,l2,s,p, pm, os;


    for (int i=0; i<=D; i++){
        max_el_line = (1 << i);
        x = 1 << (D-i+1);
        l2 = (1 << i);
        s = C*(x-1)-x;
        p = (W - l2*C - (l2-1)*s) >> 1;

        if (i == 0){
            s = 0;
        } else{
                memset(curr_line,' ',p+3);
                os = p+3;
            for (int j=0; j < pm; j++){
                memset(curr_line+os,'_',s+2);
                os += s+2;
                if (j < pm - 1){
                    memset(curr_line+os,' ',s+4);
                    os += s+4;
                }
                curr_line[os]='\0';
                printf("%s",curr_line);
                os = 0;
            }
            memset(curr_line,' ',p+3);
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (int j=0; j < max_el_line; j++){

            char val[4] = "   ";
            int curr_val = tree_values[curr_idx];

            if (curr_val > 0){
                sprintf(val,"%3d",curr_val);
            }       

            if (j == 0){
                memset(curr_line,' ',p);
                curr_line[p]='\0';
                printf("%s",curr_line);
            }

            if(j == max_el_line - 1){
                memset(curr_line,' ',p);
                curr_line[p]='\0';
                printf("%3s%s\n", val,curr_line);
            } else {
                memset(curr_line,' ',s);
                curr_line[s]='\0';
                printf("%3s%s", val,curr_line);
            }
            curr_idx++;
            pm = max_el_line;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando alguien dice "cualquier ayuda me puede servir" puede ser válido un punto de vista externo como guía para ayudar a solucionar un problema. Además pongo "parcial" porque no está la implementación pero la lógica detrás está expuesta. Con gusto daré más detalle cuando el autor de la pregunta lo solicite o cuando tenga más tiempo para trabajar en la implementación.

Comment: Pues en las politicas **sí existen** las respuestas parciales: Bajo el subtítulo [¿Tienes el mismo problema?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) cito: "...aporta los resultados de tu investigación con información adicional como una **respuesta parcial**"

Comment: Da igual, tal y como está expuesto está abierto a interpretaciones. Desde mi punto de vista no sería una respuesta, pero entiendo que lo pueda ser para otras personas

Comment: Vuelvo a citar, respecto a las respuestas parciales, "... **aunque no se obtenga una respuesta**, la persona siguiente tendrá más con que hacerle frente al desafío". Esperaré a saber si el autor ya ha resuelto el problema o si esto le sirve en algo

Comment: Entiendo eso e intentaré agregar mas información y en lo posible dibujar el árbol requerido. Cité las políticas respecto a las respuestas parciales y su alcance, ya que según tus comentarios anteriores, era algo que desconocías.